# Feed elements of a tuple to a function as arguments in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, printf, currying

In my Haskell program, I want to use printf to format a list of tuples.  I can map printf over a list to print out the values one at a time like this:

```
mapM_ (printf "Value: %d\n") [1,2,3,4]

Value: 1
Value: 2
Value: 3
Value: 4
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
mapM_ (printf "Values: %d %d\n") [(1,100),(2,350),(3,600),(4,200)]

Values: 1 100
Values: 2 350
Values: 3 600
Values: 4 200
```

But this passes a tuple to printf, not two separate values.  How can I turn the tuple into two arguments for printf?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/6237259/168034

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Function `uncurry` converts a two-argument (curried) function into a function on pairs. Here's its type signature:

```
uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
```

You need to use it on `printf`, like this:

```
mapM_ (uncurry $ printf "Values: %d %d\n") [(1,100),(2,350),(3,600),(4,200)]
```

Another solution is to use pattern matching to deconstruct the tuple, like this:

```
mapM_ (\(a,b) -> printf "Values: %d %d\n" a b) [(1,100),(2,350),(3,600),(4,200)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mapM_ (\(x,y) -> printf "Value: %d %d\n" x y) [(1,100),(2,350),(3,600),(4,200)]
```

Answer (score 2):

A type-safe alternative to `Text.Printf` is the [formatting](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/formatting) package. `Text.Printf.printf` does not ensure at compile-time that the number of formatting parameters aligns with the number of arguments and their types. Read Chris Done's article, [What's wrong with printf?](http://chrisdone.com/posts/formatting) for examples.

An example usage:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Formatting

map (uncurry $ formatToString ("Value: " % int % " " % int)) [(1,100), (2,350), ...]
map (\(x,y) -> formatToString ("Value: " % int % " " % int) x y) [(1,100), (2,350), ...]
```

It requires the GHC extension [OverloadedStrings](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions#overloadedstrings) to function properly.

While `formatToString ("Value: " % int % " " % int)` has the type `Int -> Int -> String`, uncurrying it gives the type `(Int, Int) -> String` of which the input type matches the elements in the list.

The rewriting process can be broken down; assuming `f` = `formatString ("Value: " ...)`,

```
map (\(x,y) -> f x y)  ≡  map (\(x,y) -> uncurry f (x,y))  ≡  map (uncurry f)
```

That is, first you uncurry f to achieve the function that accepts tuples, and then you perform a regular [Eta-conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) since `\(x,y) -> uncurry f (x,y)` is equivalent to simply `uncurry f`. To print each line in the result, use `mapM_`:

```
mapM_ (putStrLn . uncurry $ formatToString ...) [(1,100), (2,350), ...]
```

If you run *hlint YourFile.hs*, these rewrites will be recommended to you.