# Function composition in Haskell with tuple arguments

Tags: haskell, tuples, currying, function-composition

Sometimes I have two functions of the form:

```
f :: a -> (b1,b2)
h :: b1 -> b2 -> c
```

and I need the composition g. I solve this by changing h to h':

```
h' :: (b1,b2) -> c
```

Can you please show me (if possible) a function m, so that:

```
(h . m . f) == (h' . f)
```

Or another way to deal with such situations. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a function (b1,b2) -> b1 -> b2?

Comment: Stop...Hoogle time! [(a -> b -> c) -> ((a,b) -> c)](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+%28%28a%2Cb%29+-%3E+c%29) (transform curried function with 2 arguments into a function that takes a tuple)

Comment: @DanBurton Or alternatively, [`(strange -> indian -> food) -> ((strange, indian) -> food)`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28strange+-%3E+indian+-%3E+food%29+-%3E+%28%28strange%2C+indian%29+-%3E+food%29).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you're looking to do is to take a function that operates on *curried* arguments, `h`, and apply it to the result of `f`, which is a tuple. This process, turning a function of two arguments into a function that takes one argument that is a tuple, is called *uncurrying*. We have, from [Data.Tuple](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/Data-Tuple.html):

```
curry :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c 
   -- curry converts an uncurried function to a curried function.

uncurry :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a, b) -> c
   -- uncurry converts a curried function to a function on pairs.
```

So now we can write:

```
f :: a -> (b,c)
f = undefined

h :: b -> c -> d
h = undefined

k :: a -> d
k = uncurry h . f
```

---

Another tricky way to think of this is via an applicative functor,

```
k = (h <$> fst <*> snd) . f
```

Idea from Conor McBride, who'd write it as: `(|f fst snd|) . f` I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did only know fst and snd from Data.Tuple.

Answer (score 9):

What you want to do is *uncurry* `h`. This function takes `a -> b -> c` and converts it into `(a, b) -> c`.

```
uncurry h . f
```